# Explaining some of John Resig's ninja code

Tags: javascript

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(){
     var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
      object = args.shift();
      return function(){
              return fn.apply(object,
                   args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
      };
};


var myObject = {};
function myFunction(){
    return this == myObject;
}
assert( !myFunction(), "Context is not set yet" );
var aFunction = myFunction.bind(myObject)
assert( aFunction(), "Context is set properly" );
```

Tiny modification to Jeffery's code below helped me understand the arguments used in the inner anonymous function. I just changed the 3 lines below

```
var introduce = function(greeting) { alert(greeting + ", my name is " + this.name + " ,home no is " + arguments[1]); }

hiBob(" 456"); // alerts "Hi, my name is Bob"
yoJoe(" 876");
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: No Upvotes?  Should warrant at least 1 or 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions/arguments) object is an array-like object, it has only the length property.

Calling the slice function through the Array.prototype is a common technique to convert it to an array, so you will be able to use array functions like [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) on this example, directly.

Comment: I hate that arguments is a half baked array, so annoying

Comment: Yeah. I always thought it was lame, too.

Comment: Yes, annoying, this is one of the things that will be improved on ECMAScript 5...

Comment: @CMS Nope, `arguments` still inherits from `Object.prototype` in ES5, not from `Array.prototype`. You also forgot rather useful (although somewhat ill-conceived) **`arguments.callee`** :)

Comment: @kangax: Yes, I didn't mention it, either the deprecated arguments.caller, it's a shame that it will be still inheriting from Object.prototype, I'm just seeing the September final draft :( (http://is.gd/3Rqkb [pdf] page 70)

Answer (score 6):

`Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` creates an `Array` containing all the arguments passed to the function.

Answer (score 6):

This code creates a new method on the `Function` type named `bind` that accepts a free function as input and returns a wrapper function that calls it as if it were a method on the specified object.  This is quite similar to how a .Net delegate wraps together a function and its associated `this` reference.

Additionally, if more than one argument is supplied to `bind`, these additional arguments are prepended to the call -- this technique is also called [currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

To try to explain it in a simpler fashion, consider something like this:

```
var bob = { name: "Bob" };
var joe = { name: "Joe" };

var introduce = function(greeting) { alert(greeting + ", my name is " + this.name); }

var hiBob = introduce.bind(bob, "Hi");
var yoJoe = introduce.bind(joe, "Yo");

hiBob(); // alerts "Hi, my name is Bob"
```

Comment: Thanks. This info was useful for me to look more into that code.
Susan

Comment: Your answer was the most useful for me since I learnt about currying

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, this is what slice does

> [Array.slice(begin[,end])](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/Ecmascript/Quickref/slice.html)    The slice
>   method creates a new array from a
>   selected section of an array. The
>   original array is unaffected by this
>   but, if a string or number in one
>   array is altered, it is not reflected
>   in the other, whereas a change to a
>   referenced object can be seen in both
>   Array objects. The slice method uses
>   the zero-based array index to
>   determine the section out of which to
>   create the new array. It extracts up
>   to, but not including, the 'end'
>   element (if no 'end' is specified, the
>   default is the very last element). The
>   following code creates an array called
>   'trees' and then displays a 'slice' of
>   it:    Code:
>
> ```
> trees = ["oak", "ash", "beech", "maple", "sycamore"] 
> document.write(trees.slice(1,4))
> ```
>
> Output:  ash,beech,maple    If you
>   use a negative index for the 'end',
>   this specifies an element so many
>   places from the end. Continuing with
>   the above example, the following code
>   would display the second through the
>   third to last elements of the array:
>   Code:
>
> ```
> trees = ["oak", "ash", "beech", "maple", "sycamore"] 
> document.write(trees.slice(1,-2))
> ```
>
> Output:  ash,beech

As to what slice does given the current context, CMS has the right answer

Comment: That doesn't really answer her question.  I think she wanted to know what it did in the given context.

Comment: Ah, next time I will infer what she really wants to know :)

Comment: I think it's unfair to down-mod this answer.  I myself was going to point out that slice can be used to copy an array instead of just passing around a reference.

Comment: My fault but cdmckay's guess was right. I wanted to know what the above code did in the context. I did understand what Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) since the the very next call does a args.shift() :-)
Susan

Answer (score -1):

It turns the `arguments` object into an `Array` object so that he can call `args.shift()`.

The arguments object is an array-like object that has 0 or more numeric index properties and a `length` property

Comment: There is no `Arguments` type in JavaScript. `arguments` is a plain `Object` with zero or more numeric properties and a `length` property (an array-like object).