# Can any genius tell me what's going on in this small code? From Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja

Tags: javascript

I'm barely starting JavaScript and I'm wondering if there are any geniuses out there that can help me understand this line by line?

```
1:  Function.prototype.bind = function(){
2:   var fn = this, 
3:      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), 
4:      object = args.shift();
5:   return function(){
6:   return fn.apply(object,
7:      args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
8:  };
9: };
```

I'm just beginner, but if you can teach me, then you're awesome. I know about prototypes, call, shift, apply a bit so you can skip the beginner parts (though I think you shouldn't so other who are barely getting into JS may learn how).

Notice: I know that there's a somewhat *"similar code"* asking a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507085/explaining-some-of-john-resigs-ninja-code) but I'm asking **line by line** explanation and they're not (not duplicate) (also, you can skip line 8 & 9) :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a partial implementation, in EcmaScript 3, of the EcmaScript 5 [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method which does [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).  It makes

```
myObject.method.bind(myObject, 1, 2)(3, 4)
```

is equivalent to

```
myObject.method(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

but its also more convenient because you can do

```
var m = myObject.method.bind(myObject, 1, 2);
m(3, 4);
m(5, 6);
```

instead of

```
myObject.method(1, 2, 3, 4);
myObject.method(1, 2, 5, 6);
```

Nit: The two are not entirely equivalent, because if the first call to `myObject.method` does `this.method = somethingElse;` then the bound method would still call the original.

To break it down:

> ```
> Function.prototype.bind = function(){
> ```

Adds a method to the builtin function type.

> ```
> var fn = this,
> ```

Stores `this` which should be a `Function` in normal use so that it can be used inside a closure.

> ```
> args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
> ```

Creates an array containing the arguments to `bind`.

> ```
>   object = args.shift();
> ```

Removes the first argument from `args` and stores it in `object`.  This will be used as the `this` value for `fn` when it is applied later.

> ```
>  return function(){
> ```

returns a function that acts as a partially applied method.  This function when called

> ```
> return fn.apply(object,
> ```

calls the function to the left of `.bind` passing the first argument to `bind` as `this`.
`apply` is a special reflective method of functions which allows calling of a function with an array of arguments similar to `*args` or `**kwargs` in python, or `...` in Java.

> ```
>   args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
> ```

passes as arguments to `fn`, the arguments to `bind` followed by the argument to the closure.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say we have a function

```
function hi(a, b) { alert('hi! '+(a+b)); }
```

Define a function for every function (so you could use for example `hi.bind()`)

```
1:  Function.prototype.bind = function(){
```

fn is `this`, hence the original function (in our example `this = hi`)

```
2:   var fn = this,
```

`arguments` (the function's arguments) are not a normal array, so the following is a technique to convert it into an array which contains exactly the same elements as `arguments`

```
3:      args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
```

shifts the args, returning the first one (which is the context with which you want to call the function)

```
4:      object = args.shift();
```

this function returns a new function

```
5:   return function(){
```

`apply` is a function that allows to to call a function with a given focus and arguments. `hi(2,3)` equals `hi.apply(window, [2,3])`

```
6:     return fn.apply(object,
```

The function will be called with the arguments to `bind` and any additional arguments you pass to the function we're in (which `bind` returns)

```
7:        args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
8:     };
9: };
```

So `hi(2,3)` equals `(hi.bind(window, 2, 3))()` equals  `(hi.bind(window, 2))(3)`