# Why is array slice method called using "call"?

Tags: javascript

As seen in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174112/can-any-genius-tell-me-whats-going-on-in-this-small-code-from-secrets-of-the-j)

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(){ 
  var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments), object = args.shift(); 
  return function(){ 
    return fn.apply(object, 
      args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
  }; 
};
```

In this example why is it coded as

```
args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
```

will it be ok if I do

```
args = arguments.slice();
```

I am just trying to understand any specific reason for using `call`

And also what would be some other scenario where we will have to use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` ?

Comment: Why not simply *try* calling `arguments.slice()`...?

Comment: @deceze he he :) I was so damn sure that `arguments` is an array!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`arguments` is an *array-like* object, it is not an `Array`. As such, it doesn't have the `slice` method. You need to take the `slice` implementation from `Array` and call it setting its `this` context to `arguments`. This will return an *actual* `Array`, which is the whole point of this operation.

Answer (score 6):

`arguments` is not an array :

```
function a(){console.log(typeof(arguments)) }
```

So this `a(123)` will yield `object`

So we *borrow* the method which *can* deal with array like object  , to *slice* the object for as as if it was true array.

*Borrowing* can be made via `call` or `apply`.

`apply` will send arguments as an array ( remember : `a` for `array`) -  while `call` will send params as comma delimited values.